# Error in debian live because of nonfree firmware

Tags: debian, live-usb, firmware

This is my first time trying debian but I already tried LMDE 4 and I have no problem in LMDE 4 that's why I thought there will be also no problem using debian live that's why I downloaded [debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-lxqt.iso.torrent](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/)  and not [debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-lxqt+nonfree.iso.torrent](https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/10.4.0-live+nonfree/amd64/bt-hybrid/debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-lxqt+nonfree.iso.torrent) and now I can't download debian live + non-free firmware because I only have limited data.

When I boot in debian live I saw a non-free firmware error and show me to go in debian wiki about firmware and boot me in full screen command line.

I already downloaded the non-free firmware [`firmware.zip`](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/20200510/) but what I can do about it to work debian live? Pls don't provide me a solution to install debian because I want to boot in live usb.

Comment: Limited data, hardware that needs non-free drivers, limited storage, and first time Debian user sounds to me like a recipe for failure. Not to scare you off, but I think you need to change at least 2 of those before trying Debian again - otherwise I predict you will have a frustrating time. And I will much rather see you a happy Debian user in a year than see you fail now.

Comment: I like to fail because I also have something to learn, limited storage is not a problem to me because I can just remove windows 10 and install debian, limited data is also not a problem because I still have enough data to download the debian live plus nonfree iso...

Comment: If limited data is your concern, don't download the big isos, but download the net(work) installer - which will then download only those packages and parts you actually need beyond the bare minimum required to boot.

Comment: @planetmaker But be warned: If your installation fails, you will have to download again. It happens to me all the time, and I have installed more than 100 Debian based systems in the past 20 years.

Comment: Installing OS using network is not my type, I downloaded Debian live because I want to use it in live usb... Can firmware that I downloaded in http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/20200510/firmware.zip help me to solve my nonfree firmware problem in live boot of Debian? Thanks @Ole Tange, Planetmaker.

Comment: I'm just asking and not doing any bad to anyone why you need to give my question a -1?

Comment: A live or persistent live system cannot use proprietary drivers, that you add afterwards.  The kernel's hardware drivers can only be added that way in installed systems, On the other hand, it is possible to install Debian into an external drive (e.g. USB pendrive, if big enough) like it were installed into an internal drive. It helps if the internal drive is unplugged, disconnected or otherwise disabled during this adventure.

Comment: @sudodus So it means that even I download the Debian live plus non-free iso I can't still use the non-free firmware in live boot unless I install Debian in internal/external drive? But why in LMDE 4 I can use the gpu of my laptop and the nonfree software is pre-installed that's why I can use the gpu even in live boot in LMDE 4? it is because it's pre-installed in iso file of LMDE 4?

Comment: Because it is already there via the iso file, and available, when the kernel boots. In a live or persistent live system, the kernel is booted before the overlay system for persistence is activated, so it is 'too late' for the proprietary drivers (typically for graphics) to be added afterwards via the persistent live system.

Comment: But I'm not using persistent storage in live usb, I tried for LMDE 4 using rufus but it gives me error about missing gui.

Comment: @sudodus  
I have a question it's not related to my problem but related to live cd/usb... and It's look like you have a lot of knowledge about Linux and live boot so... Why when I successfully boot from live usb then go to file manager I always saw a same storage size of root folder in live OS which for me 1.5 GB but when I use live boot the iso file without storage only iso in virtualbox the size of root folder storage is about 700+ MB, why that so? How can I extend the storage size of root folder in live boot?

Comment: The same holds for live and persistent live in this case. But there are work-arounds. Please tell us what you want to achieve, and what is the problem. At first I thought that LMDE works for you. Did I get that wrong? - Or are you 'only' exploring new operating systems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110163/discussion-between-sudodus-and-parandroid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only option is to download [debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-lxqt+nonfree.iso.torrent.](https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/10.4.0-live+nonfree/amd64/bt-hybrid/debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-lxqt+nonfree.iso.torrent) Thank you @Sudodus for teaching me how to create a persistent live Ubuntu/Debian usb...

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution to your problem. Good luck with your persistent live system :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you read the comments against the Hybrid ISO you did download it explains your options for non-free firmware

> there is an alternative unofficial image build which includes [non-free firmware](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) for extra support for some awkward hardware

I appreciate you can't download the unofficial image build, but you have successfully downloaded the [non-free ZIP file](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/20200510/firmware.zip).

Follow the instructions on the [non-free firmware](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) page and your Debian Live should run happily.

> A suggestion, especially when installing on unfamiliar hardware, is to download the firmware archive for your platform and unpack it into a directory named firmware in the root of a removable storage device (USB/CD drive). When the installer starts, it will automatically find the firmware files in the directory on the removable storage and, if needed, install the firmware for your hardware.

- Obtain a spare USB stick (not the one containing Debian Live) and format it as FAT32
- Create the directory "firmware"
- Unzip all the files from your Non-free Firmware ZIP into that directory
- Boot the Debian Live as normal

It should find and use the appropriate non-free firmware from the second USB stick.

Please note that I haven't ever tried the Live so I can't be sure, but this is how it works for the standard installation DVD.

Comment: Didn't work, but thank you @roaima

Comment: What part didn't work, finding the non-free firmware, or that your firmware isn't supported at all?

Comment: Sorry for small details. I think base on my observation on live boot of Debian it didn't automatically search for firmware in usb fat32. It just do like before, give me a error then boot to command line. If I just can use "sudo mount /dev/sdc /media" then "sudo dpkg -i *" then use a command that will run the desktop gui but it's gives me error: "mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error" even if I solved that error I still need to know a command that will get me out in full screen command line...

Comment: I have a question it's not related to my problem but related to live cd/usb... Why when I successfully boot from live usb then go to file manager I always saw a same storage size of root folder in live OS which for me 1.5 GB but when I use live boot the iso file without storage only iso in virtualbox the size of root folder storage is about 700+ MB, why that so? How can I extend the storage size of root folder in live boot?